# Dispatch redux actions in componentWillMount won't immediately reflect in the first render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

`componentWillMount` is not recommended to use anymore, so I'm not familiar with this behavior. However, there're still some legacy codes in my project adopting `componentWillMount`. When I further digged into it, I found this weird behavior that the redux store changes doesn't immediately reflect in the first render.

I simplify the code in the following section (the complete code on codeSandBox runnable can be found [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-connect-example-forked-ss2iw?file=/components/Counter.js))

In this example, I try to set local state and redux store in the `componentWillMount`.
According to the React life cycle orders, I should be able to view these two values in the first `render()`.

```js
componentWillMount() {
  this.setState(prevState => ({counter: prevState.counter+1}));
  this.props.onIncrement();
  console.warn("componentWillMount +1");
}

render() {
  console.warn("render");
  console.warn("setState counter", this.state.counter);
  console.warn("dispatch counter", this.props.value);
}
```

Nonetheless, I got the following logs:

```
componentWillMount +1 
render 
setState counter 1
dispatch counter 0
render 
setState counter 1
dispatch counter 1
```

It renders two times and the redux store value is not updated in the first round of rendering.
On the other hand, `componentDidMount` is working as expected: (two values are updated after changes)

```
render 
setState counter 0
dispatch counter 0
componentDidMount -1 
render 
setState counter -1
dispatch counter -1
```

Can someone explain this mechanism?

Answer (score 1):

This method is now deprecated. It is called before your component is mounted. The method itself will be called before `render()`. `this.setState` - will not trigger an additional re-render.

Use componentDidMount instead for store subscriptions and any side effects.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I actually change to `componentDidMount` in my project. 
However, I don't see side effects in `onIncrement()` in the above example.
How can you explain it's prohibited to do that in `componentWillMount`~?